# How to reduce the number of points drawn using ApexCharts?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apexcharts

I have a dataset and we are going to use line chart to plot it. However, said dataset can be large and reach 2700+. When I plot all that data on the chart, it gets a bit laggy and it's really hard to navigate through the markers.
Is there any way that ApexCharts can make some data decimation so that it's easier for the user to navigate? Do I need to make a filter for that to happen?

Chart-js offers this kind of data management which is exactly what I want to do with apexchart. Here is an example on how I want the data change to happen.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/advanced/data-decimation.html